# Nginx on armv7l installation

Tags: nginx, make, arm, configure

I am trying to cross-compile Nginx for Armv7l. See the followings steps already done (following this tutorial mainly [Nginx for arm](http://tiebing.blogspot.be/2014/09/cross-compile-nginx-for-arm.html))

**Step 1**

> ./configure --without-pcre --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module

**Step 2**

> make

**Step 3**

> vi objs/Makefile
>
> Replace `CC = cc` to `CC = arm-linux-gcc`

**Step 4**

> find . -name "*.o" | xargs rm -f

**Step 5**

> make

**Step 6**

My binary file "nginx" is available in objs/nginx.
Command `file` gives the following result

> objs/nginx: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.28, not stripped

**Step 7**

> Copy this binary nginx inside `/sbin` on my arm machine and use the command `sh /sbin/nginx`
>
> nginx: line 1: syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

I cannot find any help on internet. What does that error mean ? Is my file corrupted ? Should I copy the whole `objs` folder or only the binary as I did ?

Is there an already compiled version of nginx for armv7l (I did not find one) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is either:

```
sh -c /sbin/nginx
```

Or:

```
/sbin/nginx
```

And if you have [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) correctly installed on your host, you can enjoy your ARM-version of Nginx (easier with a static one).